# Crash when casting CFArrayRef to NSArray

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, quartz-graphics

This is fine:

```
CFArrayRef windowList = CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo(kCGWindowListOptionOnScreenOnly, kCGNullWindowID);
NSLog(@"%@", (__bridge NSArray *)windowList);
```

This causes EXC_BAD_ACCESS:

```
CFArrayRef windowIDList = CGWindowListCreate(kCGWindowListOptionOnScreenOnly, kCGNullWindowID);
NSLog(@"Array %@", (__bridge NSArray*) windowIDList);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Arrays created as [`NSArray`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html)s can only contain elements that act like Objective-C objects.

Arrays created as [`CFArray`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFArrayRef/Reference/reference.html)s can contain anything, if you pass the appropriate [`CFArrayCallBacks`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFArrayRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/CFArrayCallBacks) to [`CFArrayCreate`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFArrayRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001192-CH201-F10959).

`CGWindowListCreate` is creating a `CFArray`, and filling it with things that don't act like objects, but `CGWindowListCreate` is using `CFArrayCallbacks` that don't care about that.

When you try to print this `CFArray` with the `%@` format specifier, `NSLog` sends an Objective-C `-description` message to the array.  The `CFArray` handles this by sending an Objective-C `description` message to each of its elements.  Unfortunately, its elements are not objects and so it's impossible to sending Objective-C messages to them.  Thus the crash.

Try this instead:

```
CFStringRef description = CFCopyDescription(windowIDList);
NSLog(@"Array %@", description);
CFRelease(description);
```

The `CFCopyDescription` function uses one of the `CFArrayCallbacks` functions on each element of the array, instead of trying to send an Objective-C message to each one.  The callback knows how to handle the array element, so it works fine.  I get this output in my test program:

```
2011-11-10 18:50:23.888 test[15156:707] <CFArray 0x1001140c0 [0x7fff7fd24ea0]>{type = mutable-small, count = 19, values = (
    0 : <0x7d7>
    1 : <0x2d>
    2 : <0x20>
    3 : <0x21>
    4 : <0x1e>
    5 : <0x9>
    6 : <0x7a8>
    7 : <0x2c>
    8 : <0x2e>
    9 : <0x743>
    10 : <0x32>
    11 : <0x85>
    12 : <0x695>
    13 : <0x62a>
    14 : <0x62b>
    15 : <0xa>
    16 : <0x26>
    17 : <0x18>
    18 : <0x2>
)}
```

Comment: Ah! Now that makes sense as to why it was behaving half like a C array and half like an object. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html) on `NSArray`:

> NSArray is “toll-free bridged” with its Core Foundation counterpart,
>   CFArray Reference. What this means is that the Core Foundation type is
>   interchangeable in function or method calls with the bridged
>   Foundation object, providing you cast one type to the other.
>   Therefore, in an API where you see an NSArray * parameter, you can
>   pass in a CFArrayRef, and in an API where you see a CFArrayRef
>   parameter, you can pass in an NSArray instance. This arrangement also
>   applies to your concrete subclasses of NSArray.

So the problem must be with the two methods being called. Again, from the documentation, `CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo` has return value:

> An array of CFDictionaryRef types, each of which contains information
>   about one of the windows in the current user session. If there are no
>   windows matching the desired criteria, the function returns an empty
>   array. If you call this function from outside of a GUI security
>   session or when no window server is running, this function returns
>   NULL.

and `CGWindowListCreate` has return value:

> An array of CGWindowID values corresponding to the desired windows. If
>   there are no windows matching the desired criteria, the function
>   returns an empty array. If you call this function from outside of a
>   GUI security session or when no window server is running, this
>   function returns NULL.

When you call `NSLog(@"%@",array);`, the message `description` is sent to each object in the array. Floats, BOOLs and ints do not respond to this message. For example, you will get an error for

```
NSLog(@"Printing 2: %@",2);
```

but the error goes away if you use the `int` call:

```
NSLog(@"Printing 2: %d",2);
```

For your case, `CGWindowListCreate` is returning an array of `CGWindowID` values, and these are 32 bit unsigned integers. Therefore they do no respond to `%@`, but will respond to `%u`. Hence the fix is to print the array manually using `%u`.

Comment: OK, I tried `NSLog(@"Array %ld", [(__bridge NSArray*)windowIDList count]);` and it returns 14 and `CFArrayGetCount(windowIDList)` and it also returns 14 so it appears to be a normal array but `NSLog(@"Array %@", [(__bridge NSArray*)windowIDList objectAtIndex: 1]);` still crashes.

Comment: Then the problem is that `CGWindowID` does not respond to `description`. It appears to be a 32 bit unsigned int. Try `NSLog(@"Array %u", [(__bridge NSArray*)windowIDList objectAtIndex: 0]);`

Comment: Yes thanks. I was confused as to why I was getting an array of non-objects (I expected NSNumber / CFNumber) but I understand what is going on now.